# Struggling to add to ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

So I'm making this small program for my assignment at university and I'm finding it hard to add to my list in my form. Here is my code:

```
public partial class WorkOutBeam : Form
{
    Check checkLib;
    public BindingList<ListBox> list;

    public WorkOutBeam()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void StartForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = new BindingList<ListBox>();
        listBox1.DataSource = list;
    }

    private void NewForce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewForceName forceItem = new NewForceName();
        forceItem.Show();
    }

    public void AddToForceList(string name)
    {
        list.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

NewForceName class below:

```
    public partial class NewForceName : Form
{
    public WorkOutBeam workOutBeam;
    public NewForceName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NewForceNames.Text != "")
        {
            ReferToLibs();
            workOutBeam.AddToForceList(NewForceNames.Text);
            Close();
        }
    }

    private void ReferToLibs()
    {
        workOutBeam = new WorkOutBeam();
    }

    private void NewForceName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

So I say to my program, "give me a new force." When it does, it initializes a new form of "NewForceName." I type into a text box and click 'Ok', this starts a public method shown below:

The list is a binding list which refers to the listBox as a data source. However the program tells me that the Items part is inaccessible due to its protection but I don't know how to add it as public. I tried looking in the properties of my listBox but to no avail.

Comment: Is `list` a list that you bound to the `listBox` or the `listBox` itself? If `list` is just a list, then try `list.Add(name)`.

Comment: @Fildor 'listBox' is bound to 'list'.

Comment: How do you do that? And what types are they exactly?

Comment: @Fildor `list = new BindingList<ListBox>();` then `listBox1.DataSource = list;`

Comment: Why?? This doesn't make sense at all. Wipe all of that and just add strings to `listBox1.Items` - What you created is a list of listboxes, to which you try to add strings...

Comment: @Fildor I tried that tho. Some articles from here said that to add to a `listBox`, you need to use a binding list otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to do. If it's simply strings, you certainly do not need that. See also: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netcore-3.1#examples)

Comment: Aaaaahoooo wait, ... in which class is `public void AddToForceList(string name)` ?

Comment: @Fildor Yes but why doesn't it not update, it doesn't seem to want to work - I've tried `Update()` `Refresh()` etc. but nothing.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the complete code.

Comment: @Fildor it's in the `WorkOutBeam`.

Comment: Is that the Form class where the listBox is in?

Comment: @Fildor I didn't want to add the complete code otherwise it might be a bit too much.

Comment: @Fildor yes it is.

Comment: I understand that. Just like this, it's a little bit too less. Have you heard the term [mcve] before?

Comment: @Fildor I've edited a bit, I think it's reproducible.

Comment: Sidenote: `if (NewForceNames.Text != "")` - use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourstring)` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(yourstring)`

Comment: And you are not adding to the listBox you think you are. In `ReferToLibs();` you create a new WorkoutBeam with a new listBox to which you (try to) add that string. As soon as `private void NewForce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` has finished, though, `forceItem` goes out of scope and becomes garabage collectable and with it the WorkoutBeam you just created there. Your original listBox is never touched in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
public partial class WorkOutBeam : Form
{
    Check checkLib;
    // public BindingList<ListBox> list; // get rid of this for now

    public WorkOutBeam()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /*public void StartForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = new BindingList<ListBox>();
        listBox1.DataSource = list;
    }*/

    private void NewForce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewForceName forceItem = new NewForceName(this); // pass a reference to this 
                                                         // instance of WorkoutBeam
        forceItem.Show();
    }

    public void AddToForceList(string name)
    {
        // we should do some more things here, but let's keep it simple for now
        listBox1.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

And

```
public partial class NewForceName : Form
{
    public WorkOutBeam workOutBeam;
    public NewForceName( WorkoutBeam beam ) // we take a WorkoutBeam instance as CTOR param!
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        workoutBeam = beam;
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewForceNames.Text))
        {
            workOutBeam.AddToForceList(NewForceNames.Text);
            Close();
        }
    }

    // DO NOT create new WorkoutBeams every time. Use the original.
    /*private void ReferToLibs()
    {
        workOutBeam = new WorkOutBeam();
    }*/
}
```

Disclaimer: I did not address each and every problem in this code. This is just enough so that it should "work" as intended.

Comment: The best have 100k+ :) But I am glad to help.